# Как сделать скрытую переадресацию?

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, cname

скажем у меня есть два доменных именни: one.com и two.com.

Также есть проект, на PHP, который хостится на сервере(NGINX) и доступен по следующим сылкам. http://my.server.com/**one*/ и http://my.server.com/**two*/.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда клиент в браузере задавал **one.com**, у него показывался контент из http://my.server.com/**one**/, а когда **two.com**, то показывался контент из http://my.server.com/**two**/ при этом в адрессе браузера продолжалось показываться one.com или two.com соответсвенно?

как такое сделать с помощью nginx?

Заранее спасибо.

```html
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 2048;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}


http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Websocket support
    #upstream websocket {
    #    server 127.0.0.1:<PORT>;
    #}

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
     include /etc/nginx/aliases.conf;

        #location /ws {
        #    proxy_pass http://websocket;
        #    proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        #}


        location / {
            root   /var/www/webroot/ROOT;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;

         location ~ \.php$ {
          location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
         }

        }
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}
 location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
 location ~ \.php$ {
  location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/webroot;
        }

    }

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса, пожалуйста, вашу секцию `server {...}`, чтобы не нужно было описывать все возможные варианты конфигурации.

Comment: дополнил ответ на основании приложенного вами файла. см. абзац после слова **обновление**.

Answer (score 0):

во-первых, dns-имена `one.com` и `two.com` должны резолвиться в ip-адрес вашего сервера.

во-вторых, вам надо добавить две секции `server {...}` в конфигурацию *nginx*.

1. допустим, сейчас у вас есть примерно такая секция (показана только существенная информация):

   ```
   server {
     server_name my.server.com;
     ...
     root /путь/к/каталогу;
     ...
   }
   ```

   это в случае, если код сайтов находится в каталогах `/путь/к/каталогу/one` и `/путь/к/каталогу/two`.

   вам надо дважды скопировать эту секцию и исправить директивы `server_name` и `root`, чтобы получить примерно следующее:

   ```
   server {
     server_name my.server.com;
     ...
     root /путь/к/каталогу;
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name one.com;
     ...
     root /путь/к/каталогу/one;
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name two.com;
     ...
     root /путь/к/каталогу/two;
     ...
   }
   ```

   **обновление**: директива `root` может находиться и внутри секции `location / {...}`, как в вашем вопросе. это не меняет сути — копируйте секцию `server {...}` «как есть», не меняя расположение директивы `root` (т.е., оставив её внутри секции `location / {...}`), но обязательно допишите `/one` и `/two` в конце директив `root`, как в примере выше.
2. если же каталоги `one` и `two` находятся в совсем разных местах, то, вероятно, секция выглядит примерно так:

   ```
   server {
     server_name my.server.com;
     ...
     location /one {
       root /один/путь;
       ...
     }
     location /two {
       root /другой/путь;
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

   тогда вам надо опять-таки сделать две копии секции `server`, удалив ненужные секции `location {...}`:

   ```
   server {
     server_name my.server.com;
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name one.com;
     ...
     location /one {
       root /один/путь;
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name two.com;
     ...
     location /two {
       root /другой/путь;
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

   и затем исправив `/one` и `/two` на `/`, а к директивам `root` добавить эти пути:

   ```
   server {
     server_name my.server.com;
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name one.com;
     ...
     location / {
       root /один/путь/one;
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   server {
     server_name two.com;
     ...
     location / {
       root /другой/путь/two;
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: "во-первых, dns-имена one.com и two.com должны резолвиться в ip-адрес вашего сервера." - спасибо за ответ, а можно немножко по подробней об этом?

Comment: какая именно информация вас интересует? что такое [dns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) вообще?

Comment: "dns-имена one.com и two.com должны резолвиться в ip-адрес вашего сервера." - Это что значит "резолвиться "? как это сделать?

Comment: @user1167253, «резолвиться» (от англ. resolve) — это значит, что на dns-запрос вида «получить a-запись для доменного имени такого-то» возвращается *a-запись*, содержащая требуемый ip-адрес. дальнейший «ликбез», извините, здесь неуместен (комментарии для этого не предназначены). если у вас появился новый вопрос — задайте его с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.