# Как сделать скрытую переадресацию на nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, cname

Я не правильно задал вопрос вот здесь [Как сделать скрытую переадресацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655970/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

по этому создал новый вопрос.

скажем у меня есть два доменных именни: one.com и two.com.

Также есть проект, на PHP, который хостится на сервере(NGINX) и доступен по следующим сылкам. http://my.server.com/**one**/ и http://my.server.com/**two**/.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда клиент в браузере задавал one.com, у него показывался контент из http://my.server.com/one/, а когда two.com, то показывался контент из http://my.server.com/two/ при этом в адрессе браузера продолжалось показываться one.com/**one** или two.com/**two** соответсвенно?

как такое сделать с помощью nginx?

в Apache конфигурация выглядет для этого так, а как такое же сделать на nginx?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.one.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} one.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.one.com/one/ [R]  
ErrorLog logs/one.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/one.com-access_log common
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. В nginx есть аналогичный модуль, называется http_rewrite_module. Пример, привести не могу, т.к. работаю с Apache, но вы можете посмотреть официальную документацию. Она на русском языке и там есть примеры. Надеюсь вам это поможет. http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html